# Can't create user profile on firestore after firebase.auth.getRedirectResult

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

On mobile app I use firebase Google OAuth to signIn users. As recommended for mobile I prefer firebase.auth.signInWithRedirect instead signInWithPopup.

When signin occurs the user is redirected to mobile app and my app get user details (from OAuth provider) with the promise firebase.auth.getRedirectResult.

```
    this.afAuth.auth.getRedirectResult().then((result) => {
      if (result.user) {
        this.updateUserData(result.user)
        // setTimeout( _ => this.updateUserData(result.user), 100);
      }
    })

  private updateUserData(user) {
    // Sets user data to firestore on login
    console.log(user);
    const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<User> = this.afs.doc(`users/${user.uid}`);

    const data = { 
      uid: user.uid, 
      email: user.email, 
      displayName: user.displayName, 
      photoURL: user.photoURL
    } 

    userRef.set(data, { merge: true }).then( _ => console.log('result'));

  }
```

result value is filled correctly and call to updateUserData works fine, but none record is created on firestore.

After several hours of investigation, I've observed that it works fine calling updateUserData within a setTimeout `setTimeout( _ => this.updateUserData(result.user), 100)`

I provide a [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ydkztn)

I'm not confident with this workaround, I'd like to know if someone also face this issue or if the way I've implemented it is wrong.